# Why does the CF-100 autopilot have a toggle switch labeled 'ATTACK'?

Tags: military, autopilot, avro-cf-100

I took this photograph of the autopilot controls inside the cockpit of a [CF-100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avro_Canada_CF-100_Canuck). There are a bunch of switches for the autopilot. Why does one have a label of "ATTACK" and what did turning it on/off do?

[image]

Comment: I have absolutely no reference and 100% guess on this: is it possible that "attack" means "angle of attack", not "drop bombs or file missiles" ?

Comment: It automatically guides the aircraft to an attack (target intercept) based on the flight computer inputs and radar. I can't find a really good source on it, but it has been around since the 1960's. [See this Google Books Excerpt](https://books.google.com/books?id=jliqCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT174&lpg=PT174&dq=jet+autopilot+autoattack&source=bl&ots=mrexjH7oic&sig=fsCnbJkjbu3p03-VcT_kGtolaiM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjuvKyknKvQAhUZ8YMKHVr0DHkQ6AEILzAE#v=onepage&q=jet%20autopilot%20autoattack&f=false)

Comment: @Kevin File them under M for Missile?

Comment: Automatically guides the aircraft to a preset set of coordinates or a radar return?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The [Avro Canada CF-100] Mk 4 had **collision-course fire control,** the new interception method in which the **radar and autopilot interlinked** to steer the aircraft automatically to launch the rockets in a salvo to pass through a "box" of sky at the same time as the hostile aircraft. It freed interceptors from the need to attack from behind, and in a side on interception gave a much better reflective target for the radar.
>
> — [all-aero.com](http://all-aero.com/index.php/home2/1289-avro-canada-cf-100)

By coupling the radar to the autopilot, the autopilot would steer the aircraft for a firing solution toward where the [unguided] rockets would meet the target (the CF-100 was armed with [Mighty Mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folding-Fin_Aerial_Rocket)).

[image: own work]

Come to think of it, it's the airborne version of a [Torpedo Data Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torpedo_Data_Computer).

---

> The [F4D Skyray]'s search radar would be used to locate an incoming bomber after initial vectors. The fire-control system would then direct the pilot on a **collision course** until it determined that the moment had come to fire a salvo of unguided 2.75-inch folding fin rockets. The pilot would then be **free to break away.** The collision course and rockets were necessary because there was not enough time to position the fighter for a classic attack with guns.
>
> — [U.S. Naval Air Superiority: Development of Shipborne Jet Fighters - 1943-1962](https://books.google.com/books?id=XkYcBQAAQBAJ) p.143

A similar system was also used on the [Douglas F4D Skyray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_F4D_Skyray), but it seems it was guidance only, i.e., no steering.

The Skyray text above hints as to why the CF-100 would also have a **BREAKAWAY** toggle switch.